# What is wrong with this recursive function?

Tags: c++, recursion

I have to write a recursive function (not using vector or string) to reverse a number and return it. For example if I enter 35, it should return 53. My code is (which is not working):

```
int reverse( int number )
{
    if( number < 10 )
        return number;
    number = fmod(number,10);
    return reverse( number );
}
```

If I enter 35 for example, this code gives me only 5... what happens to 3??

Comment: Why are you using `fmod`?  integer types support `%` to mod them

Comment: @NathanOliver because "return reverse( number % 10 )" is giving me errors so I use <cmath> to calculate the remainder...

Comment: Step through with a debugger, it's a very small program with very small input. That should show you exactly why this isn't working. [This should help](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: What errors? And what did you _think_ the modulo operation was doing, if not... taking the modulus? The `3` gets discarded by that, so no future call to `reverse()` can see it.

Comment: It gives you 5 because that's what your function returns, just the last digit in an integer.

Comment: `fmod(number,10)` is always smaller than `10` resulting in the second call only returning the `5`. You have to not only extract the digits but also put them together again, so your function will need at least two parameters

Comment: Your algorithm is flawed, but if `return reverse( number % 10 )` was giving you an error, then there's another problem somewhere. That line, by itself, doesn't have any problems.

Comment: @mhm check my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you allowed to pull in math library functions like `log10`?

```
#include <math.h>

int reverse(int number) {
    if (number == 0) {
        return number;
    }

    return (number % 10) * pow(10, floor(log10(number))) + reverse(number / 10);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. However I don't think I would've been able to find such an algorithm myself without a moderate math background... I tried a lot to find it myself. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You cannot expect that a recursive function taking one single int and returning an int and making last digit first could successfully reverse a number. Let's imagine `f` does it, and see what happens for resp 1234 and 4123.
if you turn right, f(1234) should return f(4123) which is a non sense because we know that they will have different values. And if you turn lest f(4123) should return f(1234) exhibiting same problem.

That means that the recursive function should have at least 2 parameters, and the simpler is `number_to_convert, number_converted_so_far`, because now you have a correct stop point when the number to convert has no more digits.

In your code, the problem is that after first recursion, your number has only one single digit (the last one) so all other digits are irremidiably lost.

Comment: took me some time to understand the argument with `f(1234)` returning `f(4321)`, but its a nice one

Comment: i did it with just a single argument

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct function.

```
int fun(int a)
{
    if(a<10)
    return a;

    int no=0,b=a;
    while(b)
    {
        no++;
        b/=10;
    }

    int l=a%10;

    return l*pow(10,no-1)+fun(a/10);

}
```

[image]